# Laravel 8, Vue 3 with Inertiajs got error while ssr setup

Tags: laravel, vue.js, server-side-rendering, inertiajs

I followed all the server-side rendering steps on inertia website docs, and installed all dependencies, but couldn't manage to set up this with Laravel 8 and Vue 3.

Got this kind of error:

```
[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of created hook 
  at <App errors= {} key=null >
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at Proxy.created (C:\Users\Name\desktop\php\laravel\infoajara-new\public\js\ssr.js:702:5)
    at callWithErrorHandling (C:\Users\Name\desktop\php\laravel\infoajara-new\node_modules\@vue\runtime-core\dist\runtime-core.cjs.js:157:36)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (C:\Users\Name\desktop\php\laravel\infoajara-new\node_modules\@vue\runtime-core\dist\runtime-core.cjs.js:166:21)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (C:\Users\Name\desktop\php\laravel\infoajara-new\node_modules\@vue\runtime-core\dist\runtime-core.cjs.js:176:21)
    at callHook (C:\Users\Name\desktop\php\laravel\infoajara-new\node_modules\@vue\runtime-core\dist\runtime-core.cjs.js:2951:5)    
    at applyOptions (C:\Users\Name\desktop\php\laravel\infoajara-new\node_modules\@vue\runtime-core\dist\runtime-core.cjs.js:2853:9)
    at finishComponentSetup (C:\Users\Name\desktop\php\laravel\infoajara-new\node_modules\@vue\runtime-core\dist\runtime-core.cjs.js:7091:9)
    at setupStatefulComponent (C:\Users\Name\desktop\php\laravel\infoajara-new\node_modules\@vue\runtime-core\dist\runtime-core.cjs.js:7003:9)
    at setupComponent (C:\Users\Name\desktop\php\laravel\infoajara-new\node_modules\@vue\runtime-core\dist\runtime-core.cjs.js:6933:11)
    at renderComponentVNode (C:\Users\Name\desktop\php\laravel\infoajara-new\node_modules\@vue\server-renderer\dist\server-renderer.cjs.js:198:17)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access the `document` variable (which is only available in client side).

You can avoid this by check if you're running the code in the server or in the browser using something like

```js
const isServer = typeof window === 'undefined'
```